# 2007 battery replacement for 15" pro. 85w now 60w? Help!

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I'm looking at a replacement battery A1175 for my 2007 15" pro (specs here: http://support.apple.com/kb/SP17), which is listed as 60w. My original battery charger was 85w. Is this going to work?

Comment: Batteries are rated in mAh and chargers in W - perhaps some links to the parts you are seeking and the exact model (Apple's support page lets you enter a serial to get exact model name in terms of year and early, mid or late when it was released.)

Comment: Thank you! Here is a link to the replacement battery: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MA348LL/A. I have edited the original question to include a link to my laptop specs.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the correct part. On the page where you linked the battery at the top right is a phone support and live chat Pre sales and apple will ensure you have the right part.

If there were no losses (there are and they are not negligible) and there were not a cutoff in the charging circuitry, then this battery would get charged fully in less than an hour from an 85 watt adapter. The circuitry limits the charging rate to prolong the batteries so you should expect between 2 and 4 hours to charge that "60 watt hour" battery. The extra "capacity" serves to run the device and peripherals and have extra to spare and still charge that battery when needed.

Comment: There are 60 watt adapters and 85 watt adapters. It appears there is some confusion coming from the phrase "watt-hour". Bmike's response basically covers everything. An extended definition of watt-hour can be found at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilowatt_hour).

Comment: Thank you very much! I called apple and macmall and they had no idea. I'm in Argentina and am getting this through a friend coming from the US so no returns possible. You were a big help.

Comment: Indeed - we are so lucky to have stores in the US. I doubt the us online store would be mad you used their pre-sales chat to get the right battery.

Comment: They weren't mad, just confused. They claimed they didn't sell the product, despite it being on their site. Anyway, all good, problem solved. Sincere thanks again.